# Is it a bad idea to attend an interview for a job you don't plan to take?

Tags: interviewing

There's a job that I've been referred to, that's quite similar to my current role.

I'm interested to find out more about the job, and to scope out how valuable I am with my current skill set.

However, I'm actually looking to move into to a different kind of role, so I possibly wouldn't accept this job if it were offered, as it's likely that I wouldn't plan to stay in it for very long, and I wouldn't want to get a reputation as a job hopper.

Are there any downsides other to attending interviews, other than the personal time taken to attend them?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not a bad idea.

I've been to many such interviews, and for several reasons I have decided that I do not want the job on offer. There are a many reasons:

1. Never skip on an interview you've agreed to. It would only get you blacklisted and gives the interviewer a bad impression of you.
2. You have a chance to learn whether there are other openings that you DO want.
3. Might serve as a fall-back if you don't get the job you wanted.
4. You gain more interview experience.
5. You learn more about your salary range.

I have been to many interviews and when it comes to salary negotiations, I know exactly what I am worth, so HR can't undercut me.

If however they were to call and told you that you are successful in your job application, tell them that you already have a job offer elsewhere. Simple as that.